# Show definition of custom database datatype

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm currently working with an existing database, which has a custom datatype called geometry (using the postgis extension). When I extract data from that column in the database all it gives me is a string with 50 chars, but I don't know how the string is created and therefore how I can figure out what the actual data is.

Is there a way to look at custom datatype definitions in postgres?
I tried `psql \dT` and `psql \dT+` but didn't see the definition.

Unfortunately I don't have pgadmin.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to see the `CREATE TYPE` statement?

Comment: Yes, something like that would be great!